# Index for for-loop not working well

Tags: r, for-loop, data-manipulation

I have two dataframe

dataframe `a`

```
a   A   1   4   7
b   B   2   5   8
c   C   3   6   9
```

dataframe `b`

```
a   A   10  13  16
b   B   11  14  17
c   C   12  15  18
```

I wish to create a new dataframe `c` which retains the first two column of `a` and add corresponding numeric elements from column 3 to 5.

I used the following code:

```
c<-data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=3, ncol=5))

 for (i in 1:5) {
     if (i==1:2) {c[,i] <- a[,i]}
     else        {c[,i] <- round((a[,i]+b[,i])/2,0)}
 }

write.xlsx(c, "c.xlsx")
```

However, the output looks like the follwing in Excel

```
    X1  X2  X3  X4  X5
1   a   #N/A    11  17  23
2   b   #N/A    13  19  25
3   c   #N/A    15  21  27
```

I think there may be something wrong with the `i==1:2` part, may I know how should I modify the code?

Thank you!

Comment: Please use `dput`. In your question, add the output of `dput(a)` and `dput(b)`.

Comment: use `%in%` rather than `==` in this case

Comment: Thank you. That works well. Since both `%in%` and `==` will return a vector of logical values, may I know why `%in%` works well in this situation while `==` doesn't?

Comment: With `i = 1`, see the output of `i == 1:2` and `i %in% 1:2`. The former produces 2 logical, because you are asking whether `i` is equal to 1 and to 2. The latter produces 1 logical, because it will ask if `i` is equal to 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be of help

```
a = read.table(header = F, stringsAsFactors = F,  text  = "a   A   1   4   7
b   B   2   5   8
c   C   3   6   9")


b = read.table(header = F, stringsAsFactors = F,  text  = "a   A   10  13  16
b   B   11  14  17
c   C   12  15  18")


# Using for loop:

c = data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=3, ncol=5))
for (i in 1:5) {
  if (i %in% 1:2) {c[,i] <- a[,i]}
  else {c[,i] <- round((a[,i]+b[,i])/2,0)}
}



# Even without a loop: 

c = cbind(a[,1:2], round((a[,3:5] + b[,3:5]) / 2, 0))
print(c)
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1  a  A  6  8 12
# 2  b  B  6 10 12
# 3  c  C  8 10 14
```